# When do the Pokemon Movies occur chronologically to the plot?

Tags: pokemon

I am wondering when each of the Pokemon Movies occur in relation to the series. particularity after which episodes because i know

- *Pokemon The Movie 2000: The Power of One* was set during Ash's, Misty's and Tracy's travels though the Orange Islands
- a bit of the start of *Pokemon The First Movie: Mewtwo Strikes Back* was actually seen in the series (when Mewtwo destroys and escapes from the Team Rocket Research Facility just as Jessie, James and Meowth return)

But i don't know when the events of the movies occurs in relation to Ash's adventure.

Comment: do you want a list

Comment: @Dragon more or less. it's up to the poster how they want to format it. just so long as it does answer the question in pointing out when each movies occurs in relation to the plot of the series

Answer (score 5):

### GEN I & II Pokemon Original Series (Kanto and Johto)

- *Pokémon: The First Movie—Mewtwo Strikes Back (Mewtwo's Counterattack)*

  Ash got all the badges and haven't fought the league yet. Could be anywhere between 64 and 74.
- *Pokémon: The Movie 2000—The Power of One (Mirage Pokémon: Lugia's 
  Explosive Birth)*

  Between 86 and 115 because he still has the Lapras.
- *Pokémon 3: The Movie—Spell of the Unown (Emperor of The Crystal Tower: ENTEI)*

  Between 156 and 165. Brock used Zubat in movie, gets Golbat in 165.
- *Pokémon 4Ever—Celebi: Voice of the Forest (Celebi: The Meeting that Traversed Time)*

  Between 201 and 209. Ash uses Bayleef, obtained in 201.
- *Pokémon Heroes: Latios and Latias (Guardian Gods of the Capital of Water: Latias and Latios)*

  Between 247 and 257. Misty obtained Politoad in 247, Ash got Larvita Egg in 257 which wasn't with him in the movie.

### GEN III Pokemon Advanced Generation (AG) Hoenn

- *Jirachi Wish Maker (Wishing Star of the Seven Nights: Jirachi)*

  Between AG 004 and AG 047. May's Torchic only knows Ember and Peck in the movie and learns quick attack in AG 047.
- *Destiny Deoxys (Visitor from the Sky-Splitting: Deoxys)*

  Between AG 058 and AG 066. Ash has Trokoal but doesn't have Grovyle.
- *Lucario and the Mystery of Mew (Mew and the Aura Hero: Lucario)*

  Between AG 082 and AG 018. May gets Combusken at 082, Ash gets Snorunt at 108.
- *Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea (The Pokémon Ranger and the Prince of the Sea: Manaphy)*

  Between AG 148 and the end of the series at AG 192. Brock has Marshtomp (obtained in AG 148) and that's the latest Pokemon that the team acquired in the region shown in the movie.

### GEN IV Pokemon Diamond and Pearl (DP) Sinnoh

- *The Rise of Darkrai (Dialga VS Palkia VS Darkrai)*

  Between DP 038 and DP 055. Brock already hatched Happiny, but Buizel is still Dawn's.
- *Giratina and the Sky Warrior (Giratina and the Bouquet of the Frozen Sky: Shaymin)*

  Between DP 085 and DP 100. Ash has Gliscor, but Turtwig hasn't evolved yet.
- *Arceus and the Jewel of Life (Arceus: To Conquering Space-Time)*

  Between DP 132 and DP 163. Ash has a Monferno which he acquired in 132 and evolves in DP 163.
- *Zoroark—Master of Illusions (Phantom Ruler: Zoroark)*

  Between 171 and the end of series at 192. Dawn has Togekiss, and that was the last Pokemon acquired in the series.

### GEN V Pokemon Best Wishes (BW) Unova

- *White—Victini and Zekrom (Victini and the Black Hero: Zekrom)*
- *Black—Victini and Reshiram (Victini and the White Hero: Reshiram)*

  Between BW 024 and BW 077. Ash has hatched Scraggy, but only has Tepig.
- *Kyurem vs. the Sword of Justice (Kyurem vs. the Sacred Swordsman: Keldeo)*

  Between BW 077 and BW 116. This one is debatable because Ash had Pignite but probably doesn't have Charizard (otherwise, he would've used it), but he could have kept it in the ball and there was no other evidence.
- *Genesect and the Legend Awakened (ExtremeSpeed Genesect: Mewtwo Awakens)*

  Between BW 116 and the end of the series BW 144. Ash has his Charizard and that was the last Pokemon acquired.

### GEN VI Pokemon XY/Pokemon XY&Z (XY) Kalos

- *Diancie and the Cocoon of Destruction*

  Between XY 038 and XY 052. Ash's Froakie knows Cut (it's actually Laido) but is still a Froakie.
- *Hoopa and the Clash of Ages (The Archdjinni of the Rings: Hoopa)*

  Between XY 067 and XY 100. Serena has Braixen but Ash doesn't have Greninja yet. Clemont is also traveling with Ash again, so wait until after their battle when he rejoins them.
- *Volcanion and the Mechanical Marvel (Volcanion and the Exquisite Magearna)*

  Between XY 110 and XY 126. Ash has Noivern but his Goodra hasn't rejoined the group yet.

### GEN VII Pokemon Sun & Moon (SM) Alola (?)

- *I Choose You* and *Everyone's Story*

  These two movies take place in an alternate timeline and are retellings of the Orginal Series and the Orange Islands, respectively. Despite airing alongside the Alola-based series, they have no bearing whatsoever on it.

I base these through the Pokemon in the team including (Ash's friends at the time) in the movie and the moves they've used. The original series might be a bit off because I have the banned episode as episode 38 and the safari episode as well. The first episode means that the movie was at least after that episode; the second episode means that the movie was definitely before that episode with one exception of Keldeo. It could be anywhere between the two episodes, so it's why there's a gap. The reasoning for the episodes is there as well. The source of info was from Bulbapedia and my Pokemon anime and movie collection.

Answer (score 4):

After a quick Google sesrch, I found this from [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100707224114AAclKqT):

> AG stands for the Advanced Generation and DP stands for the Diamond
>   and Pearl series.
>
> Episode 67 (The Pi-Kahuna), Pokemon the First Movie: Mewtwo Strikes
>   Back, Episode 68 (Make Room for Gloom)
>
> Episode 105 (Charizard Chills), Pokemon the Movie 2000: The Power of
>   One, Episode 106 (The Pokemon Water War)
>
> Episode 155 (The Forest Grumps), Pokemon the Movie 3: Spell of the
>   Unown, Episode 156 (The Psychic Sidekicks)
>
> Episode 205 (The Kecleon Caper), Pokemon 4Ever: Celebi: Voice of the
>   Forest, Episode 206 (The Joy of Water Pokemon)
>
> Episode 256 (Just Add Water), Pokemon Heroes, Episode 257 (Lapras of
>   Luxury
>
> AG Episode 34 (Having a Wailord of a Time), Jirachi: Wish Maker, AG
>   Episode 25 (Win, Lose, or Drew!)
>
> AG Episode 85 (Sky High Gym Battle), Destiny Deoxys, AG Episode 86
>   (Lights, Camerupt, Action)
>
> AG Episode 134 (A Real Cleffa-Hanger), Lucario and the Mystery of Mew,
>   AG Episode 135 (Numero Uno Articuno)
>
> AG Episode 183 (Aipom and Circumstance), Pokémon Ranger and the Temple
>   of the Sea, Episode 184 (Strategy Tomorrow - Comedy Tonight!)
>
> DP Episode 39 (Steamboat WIllies), The Rise of Darkrai, DP Episode 40
>   (Top-Down Training)
>
> DP Episode 86 (Arriving in Style!), Giratina and the Sky Warrior, DP
>   Episode 87 (The Psyduck Stops Here!)
>
> DP Episode 135 (Beating the Bustle), Arceus and the Jewel of Life, DP
>   Episode 136 (Hustle and Gateway to Ruin!)

Also, you can find more information about how the Pokemon movies fit into the timeline [here](http://forums.bulbagarden.net/index.php?threads/where-would-the-pokemon-movies-fit-in-best-with-the-anime-series.151080/), [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/217-pokemon/68708478), and [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110628152339AAZ8Pt8).

Please refer to this relevant question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73310/what-is-the-correct-viewing-order-for-the-pokemon-tv-series-and-movies

In addition, you can find a complete list of all the Pokemon movies [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_films).

Comment: how come you only have up to Diamond and Pearl?

Comment: @Dragon It was just the results from the first source, I can go through and add the rest when I get the chance (it was supposed to just be a preliminary answer)

Answer (score 0):

Slight Correction to the 8th movies time frame.

> Lucario and the Mystery of Mew (Mew and the Aura Hero: Lucario)
>
> Between AG 082 and AG 018. May gets Combusken at 082, Ash gets Snorunt at 108.

In truth this actually occurs later in the series

After AG134: A Real Cleffa-Hanger where Brock leaves his Ludicolo at the Pewter Gym.

Before AG147: where James drops Chimecho at a family mansion to recover and catches a Mime Jr.

This is more easily noticed by the fact that May has Squirtle and Ash has Phanpy; which both happen at the beginning of Battle Frontier.

Also

The 9th Movie Time frame - Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea

After AG182: Channeling the Battle Zone! where Ash Catches Aipom.

Before AG191: Once More With Reeling! where Mays Combusken evolves into Blaziken.